# How to Split Based on Multiple Defined Delimiters

Tags: powershell, split

I have the below Powershell script that I pull only the first two columns from due to not being able to get the others separated properly.  I'd like to force my import to always split into 7 columns with each data set included.

My Current PS Script:

```
$serverNames = Get-Content "C$\app\test\ServerList2.txt"
$ServerList = @()

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
    $ServerList += Import-Csv "C$\app\test\$serverName.txt" -Header "Extension","Server IP","TRUE","NIC","Comments","PCName" |
    Select-Object *, @{n='Server Name';e={$serverName}}
}

$ServerList
```

My Two Sample Files:
Sample 1:

```
; sample entries
; StationID, MAC Address,      Recording Enabled
; AddressType = MAC
; 5201,       00.0d.29.0b.cd.34, TRUE
; 5202,       00.0D.29.0B.D9.30, TRUE


; StationID, IP Address,      Recording Enabled
AddressType = IP4

10000, 192.168.1.137, TRUE, 1         ; My Comments     PCName
10001, 192.168.1.28, TRUE          ;My Comments
10003, 192.168.1.63, TRUE,2          ; My Comments     PCName
```

Sample 2:

```
; sample entries
; StationID, MAC Address,      Recording Enabled
; AddressType = MAC
; 5201,       00.0d.29.0b.cd.34, TRUE
; 5202,       00.0D.29.0B.D9.30, TRUE


; StationID, IP Address,      Recording Enabled
AddressType = IP4

10010, 192.168.1.29, TRUE,1         ; My Comments 4
10040, 192.168.1.7, TRUE          ; My Comments 5     PCName
10100, 192.168.1.14, TRUE,2          ; My Comments 6    PCName
```

The data I'm concerned with is just the rows starting with numbers.  As you can tell though not all rows have the same delimiters which is adding to the complexity.  I'm trying to get the output to look like the below.

```
Extension   IP Address      TRUE    NIC   Comments        PC Name   Server Name
10000       192.168.1.137   TRUE    1     My Comments 1   PCName1   Server1
10001       192.168.1.28    TRUE          My Comments 2             Server1
10003       192.168.1.63    TRUE    2     My Comments 3   PCName3   Server1
10010       192.168.1.29    TRUE    1     My Comments 4             Server2
10040       192.168.1.7     TRUE          My Comments 5   PCName5   Server2
10100       192.168.1.14    TRUE    2     My Comments 6   PCName6   Server2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Import-CSV` (and the CSV-format in general) uses a single delimiter. If your files have multiple delimiters and "optional" fields (not null-values, but missing values), then it's not CSV. The best way is to create a custom parser using regex. Ex.

```
$regex = '^(?<Extension>.+?),\s?(?<IPAddress>.+?),\s+(?<TRUE>\w+?)(?:,\s?(?<NIC>\d))?\s+?;\s?(?<Comments>.+?)(?:\s{2,}(?<PCName>\w+))?$'

$serverNames = Get-Content "C$\app\test\ServerList2.txt"
$ServerList = @()

foreach ($serverName in $serverNames) {
    Get-Content -Path "C$\app\test\$serverName.txt" | ForEach-Object {
        if($_ -match $regex) {
            $ServerList += New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $Matches |
            Select-Object -Property "Extension","IPAddress","TRUE","NIC","Comments","PCName", @{n='Server Name';e={$serverName}}
        }
    }
}

$ServerList
```

Demo and explanation of regex: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yJ2aZ4/1)

Comment: thank you very much.  and thanks for the regex site it really lays out how the entire sequence works which is something i've been missing.

Comment: Question.  I ran this and it works great on my files however i did encounter a small problem apparently some sites will put their stuff in this format which the provided regex doesn't work on.  45239, 10.1.11.111, TRUE   ; My Comments  PC Name  agent.  They have a space and tab after comments which causes both comment and PC Name to go on the same line.  I'd like to also ignore the Agent after the PC name.  Thoughts?

Comment: No problem. I'm actually very happy with the solution. Don't think I've ever used named groups as a dynamic text-parser before. It could've saved me many lines of code over the years. :-)

Comment: Then add the new sample in the regex101 line and tune the regex until it works. That's how you learn. The regex is just a proof of concept to show you a solution that works with the provided sample data. This isn't a store. :-)  As for the "agent"-part, you could either strip it away by modifying the property or replace the end of the regex from `$` to `(?:\s+agent)?$`. Welcome to StackOverflow and good luck

Comment: Btw. space and tab still counts as two "whitespace-chars" which is covered by the code with `\s{2,}`. The error in the sample in your comment (which may have lost some characters when posted here) is that `PC Name` are two words. The regex only matches a single word computername (anything else isn't a valid computername anyways)